# use function arguments or variable in postgres function

Tags: postgresql, functions, alter-table

I want to set the default value for the column `building` and `floor` in my table `points` in the below function called `test(b,f)`

```
Create or replace function test(b text, f text) returns void as
$$
Begin
Alter table points alter COLUMN building set default b;
Alter table points alter COLUMN floor set default f;
End;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

When I run `select test('Shopping Mall','03')` it gives me below error:

```
 column b does not exist
```

It seems that I cannot use a function arguments `b` in the `alter ...` query?

Comment: Exactly, you cannot do that.  But really, why do you want this?

Comment: (If you really need this, you can build a dynamic SQL and execute it.)

Comment: I want to dynamically set my table column default value so every time when I insert row data, there is no need to key in the default value again and again. I have found a way to do this by using trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution by using function triggers. I didn't dynamically change the default value but I used trigger function to update the column value before `insert` action. It can achieve the same result.

```
Create or replace function update_value() 
Returns Trigger AS $$
BEGIN
IF NEW.floor ISNULL THEN
    NEW.floor :=(select floor from buildings where my_current_location='yes');
END IF;

IF NEW.building ISNULL THEN                                         
    NEW.building :=(select name from buildings my_current_location='yes');      
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END $$ Language 'plpgsql';
```

Also you need to add a trigger to the table:

```
Create triggers update_value_trigger Before Insert On points For each row execute procedure update_value();
```

Comment: Well, this now makes sense. Changing the default every time, well, it means that the default is not default.  Still, are you sure you have to use a trigger? Can't you do this from the INSERT statement? It would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I cannot because I am using QGIS software to draw a point with all attributes and write into a table, not using INSERT statement. To do that, I need to hack the QGIS software.